# Net Maui android app shows blank page after login (Azure B2C) the next time after a successful login and logout

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, maui

I am doing a login flow in .net maui, first time I try the flow works properly showing the landing page, after a successful logout, I try login again and one blank page is shown instead of the landing page.

I am using shell and the login code is the following

```
 public partial class LoginPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IAuthNService _authNService;

    public LoginPageViewModel(IAuthNService authNService)
    {
        _authNService = authNService;
    }

    [ICommand]
    async void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _authNService.LoginAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            var token = result?.IdToken;  
            if (token != null)
            {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var data = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
                var claims = data.Claims.ToList();
                if (data != null)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(DashboardPage)}", true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MsalClientException ex)
        {
            await Toast.Make(ex.Message).Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Toast.Make(ex.Message).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Current flow]

Comment: See attached image for reference

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause of the issue based on this information alone. However, it looks like you're trying to handle exceptions in your code when performing the login. It would be helpful to check the exception message to see if it provides any hints on why the landing page is not displayed after successful logout.